# Access a code behind property in xaml

Tags: wpf

this is my first ever post, so it moght not look all that good, but I'll try my best...

I've been searching the net for this one for some hours now, it might sound silly but I haven't been able to find the answer.

I have Window class, and in the .cs file I have some properties, for example

```
public ImageSource Obal { get; set; }
```

Then in the designer I added some Images, buttons, etc. Also set the Window's Name: **Name="Somename"**

I would like to know how to access that property, so I can, for example, set some image's source property to it, like this:

**Image Name="Blah" Source="Obal"**

Now I know i can set the Source value through binding:

**Source="{Binding ElementName=karta, Path=Obal}"**

But do I have to so it like this everytime? All those properties are from the Window class anyway...And Im also asking because I want to change **image.Source** in **Storyboard** in **Image.Style**...and I cant use bindings there...

I hope that I was clear and I thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To access code behind property in XAML file, you need to follow 3 steps:

1. Refer the namespace in xaml file like:

   ```
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AccessACodeBehindPropertyinXaml"
   ```
2. Provide a key to the namespace you have referred in Windows.Resources markup. This key will allow to access any class, Property of the referred namespace in your XAML file e.g.

   ```
   <Window.Resources>
           <local:ImageClass x:Key="imageClass"/>
   </Window.Resources>
   ```
3. Now you just need to bind your control's property in XAML, by using Source & Path properties of Binding class as below:

   ```
   <Label Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource imageClass}, Path=ImageName}" Name="label1" />
   ```

I have written a sample application that binds a class property to a label control. Have a look

MainWindow.xaml.cs file:

```
namespace AccessACodeBehindPropertyinXaml
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();                       
        }
    }

    public class ImageClass
    {
        string m_ImageName;

        public ImageClass()
        {
            m_ImageName = "My Image Name";
        }
        public string ImageName
        {
            get
            {
                return m_ImageName;
            }
            set
            {
                m_ImageName = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="AccessACodeBehindPropertyinXaml.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AccessACodeBehindPropertyinXaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="ImageWindow">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ImageClass x:Key="imageClass"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource imageClass}, Path=ImageName}" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="159,126,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="109" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Please let me know, if you need any more clarification.

Comment: Please don't indent text unless you want it to be formatted as code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I was hoping there would be more sthraightforward way of accessing that property, not through binding...Because with this property I'm trying to set an Image's source inside storyboard, which is inside its style, and it can't be done with bindings (I get "Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline tree for use across threads"), only with StaticResource...which is useless for me, because that property is set in Window's constructor.